# Printing breaks bootstrap layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, printing

I have the following page:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 1,1 in small row 1 in xs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 1,2 in small row 2 in xs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 2,1 in small row 3 in xs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 2,2 in small row 4 in xs</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This page appears as expected when viewing (i.e. there's 2 columns and 2 rows on small+ screens and 4 rows on mobile) however the problem is when trying to print.

When I do CTRL+P in Chrome I get the following preview:

[image]

The page size is set to A4. The issue does not occur in Firefox (but does also occur in IE and Edge)

Any idea how to get the print view to render the small (or medium) layout instead of the mobile view?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Demo

https://so51099397.surge.sh/

(I feel the fix that I have implemented is a little too much but I don't think there is any other way to fix the problem)

(If you are wondering why I hosted a site instead of something like SO snippet or jsfiddle I have explained in the comment)

## Explanation

**Why am I getting "mobile" view in print?**

1. `width of A4 = 210mm ≈ 8.27 in ≈ 595 px (72 dpi)`
2. `xs` applies when `width < 768px`
3. So technically what chrome is doing is correct and what other browsers are doing is incorrect

**How to fix this?**

1. Bootstrap is written in [mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-mobile) pattern.
2. Meaning the stylesheet looks something like this:

```css
    .col-xs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .col-sm-6 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
```

3. Now somehow if I unwrap rules inside `@media (min-width: 768px)` only during print, my problem will be solved.
4. To implement this we will get all rules inside `@media (min-width: 768px)` using `document.styleSheets` (don't forget to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` in bootstrap `<link>` or else you would get an error while accessing the stylesheet)
5. Once we have all those styles, we'll wrap them in a `<style>` and append in `<head>` on `beforeprint` event
6. On `afterprint` event we'll remove that `<style>`

Code (same as in demo) :

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", function(){
    let printStyleSheet = document.createElement("style");
    printStyleSheet.classList.add("print-stylesheet");
    document.head.appendChild(printStyleSheet)

    let printRulesText = "";
    Array.from(document.styleSheets).forEach(styleSheet => {
        Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules)
        .filter(rule => rule.media && /(min-width: 768px)/g.test(rule.media.mediaText))
        .forEach(rule => {
            Array.from(rule.cssRules).forEach(rule => printRulesText += rule.cssText)
        })
    })
    printStyleSheet.innerHTML = printRulesText;
})
window.addEventListener("afterprint", function(){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".print-stylesheet")).forEach(style => style.remove())
})
```

**Note:** This will give you the tablet view (sm) if you want the medium desktop view (md) you'll have to unwrap both, `min-width: 768px` as well as `min-width: 992px` similarly for large desktop (lg) also

**Will this work?**

1. It works for the code in the question
2. It should work for the other components too.

**Can I fix it by applying `html, body { width: 769px }` during print? (as 769 > 768)**

1. No it won't work because media queries work on `viewport` and not on width of html or body

**Okay so can I append `<meta name="viewport" content="width=769">` and remove other viewport meta during print? (as 769 > 768)**

1. Umm... No. It doesn't work. (I think it should tho but somehow doesn't work)

**Any other fixes?**

1. Manually override `xs` styles like @Arex did
2. Get the bootstrap css source code and modify it using `print` media queries something like this:

   ```
    .col-xs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .col-sm-6 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }

    /* add such rules everywhere */
    @media print{
        .col-sm-6 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Put all contents of the current page in an `iframe` with `width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;` and make everything else `display: none;`. But I feel it won't work because if the `iframe` gets a scrollbar the contents out of the view won't get printed. Also looks much more hackish

*PS: It's pretty obvious but let me explicitly say this... The fix implemented (as seen in the demo) does not fix just the grid system or the snippet in the question... But fixes the behaviour of **ALL components** (button, table, inputs, grid, etc) by faking a `min-width: 768px` media query. That's what the OP wants. Not individually fixing the components*

PPS: Read Floyd's comment we can create print stylesheet during build-time itself which is better

Comment: Don't use an external site for the example, use jsfiddle or the built in SO system or something for maintainability :)

Comment: @Islam I used a external hosted site on purpose because if I use SO snippet or jsfiddle an `iframe` will be printed not the actual content. Try printing the snippet in the question you will get 2x2 columns instead of 1x4 as in the screenshot. Also could have used something like stackblitz but again the code is not the same. They put some other stuffs too. If I want the exact code I have to host a website. :)

Comment: Also, unrelated, I don't know why  8.27 in is 595 px . The CSS specification states that a CSS pixel is 1/96 inches so it should be more like 794 px. That's what you get @ 96DPI too so no idea why Chrome would default to 72.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks and Welcome! And chrome kinda does follow the spec... check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0s7qL9pa/11/)... Here 1in = 96px on screen as well as in the print... So for elements, res is 96 ppi... But somehow for pages and viewports, I guess the res is 72 ppi (maybe because pdf page size res doesn't fall under css spec)

Comment: @FloydKosch Yeah fair, I get your point. I guess it's easy to statically extract the overrides into a `print.css` with tools such as postcss. Once I'm free I'll write another answer which does that.

Comment: I found that dynamically altering CSS at print time works well, but there were limitations. For example, Edge doesn't expose the same styleSheet properties that other browsers do, so the above javascript results in empty text.  And Safari doesn't have the beforeprint/afterprint events.  But almost all browsers support **@media print{...}**, and your dynamic process could be run as a development process, once, from the application in Chrome, Firefox, etc, to get the content to place inside those brackets in a static CSS file. No manual build, all browsers benefit, refresh when in doubt.

Comment: @FloydKosch "dynamic process could be run as a development process, once, from the application" Ahh so you're saying instead of doing the extracting on `beforeprint` if can be done once and appended in style tag wraping them all in a print media. Yeah makes so much more sense. I wonder why didn't I do that in the original answer xD Thanks for pointing it out will be helpful to others reading.

Comment: Exactly.  And everything needed to do that is already here in your post. (Thanks for that, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Use `@media print` to fix this. If you print preview it shows the layout for sm.

Here is the working code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        @media print
        {
            .col-xs-12
            {
                width:50%;
                float:left;
            }
        }
        
    </style>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 1,1 in small row 1 in xs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 1,2 in small row 2 in xs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 2,1 in small row 3 in xs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p>Column 2,2 in small row 4 in xs</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If at any time I want to change my small layout then I need to update the entire print stylesheet, also this means I need to basically override bootstrap which kind of defeats the point of using it.

Comment: Yes correct @media print tackles the issue properly. Nice Work! Arex

Comment: @apokryfos I am only changing what bootstrap  shows while printing(works fine for every other mode). If you dont want to apply this for every element with col-xs-12 put the ones you need in a class use that class. If you change your small layout (which i believe you mean to say like changing from sm-6 to sm-3) all you have to do is change the width and not the "whole" styling.

Comment: @Arex I don't want to override the bootstrap grid . I just want chrome  to do what firefox does (really don't care about IE)